# Rust visibility across files in same folder

Tags: rust, module, visibility

I have divided my Rust project into multiple files in same folder for tidiness. Now each file is perceived as a mod of its own and I have to mark everything `pub(crate)`. Is there a way to publicize all symbols in a file for same-crate usage, or mark files as not modules of their own but a part of my `main.rs`?

Comment: you can use `include!(<path>)` macro witch works similarly to c #include

Comment: Why is `pub(crate)` bad for you?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think it clutters the code too much. I feel like my case falls between that gap where it's long enough to have a file of its own, but not a mod of its own. Maybe I'm still thinking in C++.

Comment: @JakubDóka this is precisely what I was looking for, thanks. If you're willing to repost as an answer, I can mark it.

Comment: You can use `include!()`, but that's a bad idea. `pub(crate)` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust has a builtin macro [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html), that works similarly to `#include` in c but mind that that's not its intended use. The macro is usually used for including generated files like opengl bindings that are not intended for editing. Rust analyzer will not offer intelisense in included files. As @Chayim Friedman mentioned, using `pub(crate)` is the way, BUT:

```
struct A; // private struct
pub(crate) struct B; // public to whole crate
pub struct C; // public to other crates, but only if this is library
pub(super) struct D; // public to parent module
```

If you have `main` I assume your project is application and not a library so you need just `pub`.